# How to remove Hover Border (FocusRing ) of listview items in UWP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

[image]

My listview item consists of a TextBox as shown in the picture and I have given border thickness = "0" for the TextBox.

But I'm hot able to remove the Mouse Pointer Hover border(Focus Ring As Shown in Picture).

What property should I override to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a border reveal effect which is part of the Fluent Design System language. The effect itself is part of the controls template but you can remove it by creating a custom version of a control's template without it. You can find the generic templates on this path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\
>          {version}\Generic\generic.xaml

You can copy the default style, remove the reveal border and use your custom style instead of the default.

If you want to turn the effect off for `ListView` and `GridView` in general, you could overwrite the `RevealBrush` resources by "transparent" `SolidColorBrush` resources.

Check [this interesting blog post](https://edi.wang/post/2018/12/31/how-to-remove-default-fds-effects-in-uwp-apps) from app developer who hit this problem with his app as well.